# Interactive brokers basic api line handler code?

Tags: python, interactive-brokers

I am experiencing some issues with my connection to IB. All my data feeds work well BUT what is NOT working effectively is the connection handling to IB.  I start my python script using a linux mint cron process and the data starts to flow down a ZMQ pipe.

BUT my exception handling is non existant and I was wondering if there is anything I can look at that would allow me to determine the status of the IB link to the data servers and take action based on the result. So if it started correctly THEN the data stopped, stop the line, cancel the existing data feeds and try to restart as many times as is reasonable.  I can't seem to find any code on the IB site that covers this.
thank you